How is the standard CNOT gate derived from $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I_1 - Z_1)(I_2 - X_2)}$
Just to set the stage, I am currently taking an introduction course in QC as a Computer Science major, and I have no experience in physics and quantum mechanics, and my math knowledge is basic.
I encountered this representation: $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I_1 - Z_1)(I_2 - X_2)}$ of the CNOT gate on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate, and I thought I could quickly derive it myself, but alas to no avail.
I tried following the definitions mentioned, such that $e^{i\Theta U} = (\cos \Theta)I + (i \sin \Theta)U$ where I interpreted $U = (I_1 - Z_1)(I_2 - X_2)$ however on the wikipedia page it says that $U = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(I - U)}$ which is confusing to me as the U is on both sides of the equation, but also because this suggests that
$e^{i\Theta U} = (\cos \Theta)I + (i \sin \Theta)e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(I - U)}$ which only makes things more complicated and I still have a matrix in the exponent of $e$ but in an even more complicated expression.
I tried asking chatgpt to help me with this, but it does not really answer well, and I am not convinced what it is saying is even correct.
So is there a human out there who can help me derive that standard 2 qubit CNOT from $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}(I_1 - Z_1)(I_2 - X_2)}$?

related post

$CNOT$ has eigenvalues +1 for $|0+\rangle, |1+\rangle, |0-\rangle $ and -1 for $|1-\rangle$.
If we were to write $CNOT$ as an exponential it would therefore be $e^{0\times |0+\rangle \langle0+| + 0\times |0-\rangle \langle0-| + 0\times |0-\rangle \langle0-| + i\pi |1-\rangle \langle 1-|} = e^{i\pi (|1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes |-\rangle \langle -|)}$.
We can then use $|1\rangle \langle1| = \frac{I-Z}{2}$ and  $|-\rangle \langle -| = \frac{I-X}{2}$ to get the desired result.


Observe that the CNOT has eigenvalues $\pm1$, with the $-1$ eigenvalue having a one-dimensional eigenspace spanned by the eigenvector $|1,-\rangle\!\langle 1,-|$.

Observe that $(I-Z)/2=|1\rangle\!\langle1|$ and $(I-X)/2=|-\rangle\!\langle -|$. Thus $(I_1-Z_1)(I_2-X_2)/4=|1,-\rangle\!\langle 1,-|$.

Observe that if $P$ is a matrix of the form $P=|\psi\rangle\!\langle \psi|$ for some state $|\psi\rangle$, then $e^{i\pi P}=I -2P$. Apply this to the case of the CNOT and get the result.


